Google API OAuth2 - Delete a file in Shared Drive
I am using a PSH script to update a csv file to a Google Shared drive. The upload works fine. I need to add a delete section to delete the file before uploading a new version. When I used HTTP Method DELETE I get
Deleting file: file.csv with ID: 1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-4
Failed to delete file ID 1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-4. Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
The file is there. The account has full perms. Using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
Any suggestions? I am new at this. :)
File uploaded using PSH and Google OAuth 2. When deleting the same file, it gives 404 Not Found.
# Set the Google Auth parameters
$params = @{
    Uri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    Body = @{
        refresh_token = $RefreshToken
        client_id = $ClientID
        client_secret = $ClientSecret
        grant_type = 'refresh_token'
    }
    Method = 'Post'
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

# Get the access token
$accessToken = (Invoke-RestMethod @params).access_token

# Specify the shared drive ID and file name
$teamDriveId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxPVA"
$fileName = "file.csv"


# Step 1: Search for specific file name within the shared drive without specifying parents
$searchUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name='$fileName' and trashed=false&corpora=drive&driveId=$teamDriveId&supportsAllDrives=true&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true"
$searchHeaders = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
}
$searchResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $searchUri -Method Get -Headers $searchHeaders

Write-Host "Search response: $($searchResult | ConvertTo-Json)"

# Step 2: Delete files if found
if ($searchResult.files) {
    foreach ($file in $searchResult.files) {
        $fileId = $file.id
        Write-Host "Deleting file: $fileName with ID: $fileId"

        $deleteUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$fileId?supportsAllDrives=true"
        try {
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $deleteUri -Method Delete -Headers $searchHeaders
            Write-Host "Deleted file ID $fileId successfully."
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Failed to delete file ID $fileId. Error: $_"
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "No instances of $fileName found in the shared drive."
}


In your showing script, $deleteUri returns https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/=true. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. So, how about the following modification?
From:
$deleteUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$fileId?supportsAllDrives=true"

To:
$deleteUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?supportsAllDrives=true"

By this modification, $deleteUri returns https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/###fileId###?supportsAllDrives=true. Also, I confirmed that the modified script worked.

Thank you for the response. I added your recommendations and it worked. Thank you so much!!!!!!!

@Chris Lynch Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
